# How to customize comment functionality in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and i want to approve the comment programmatically whenever any user comment on blog post,so i have created plugin and i am using this code:

add_filter('wp_insert_comment','sandy_approve_comment');

```
function sandy_approve_comment($comment_id) {

    // Get the comment based on the incoming ID
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );

    // Set its approved comment to 1
    $comment->comment_approved = 1;

    // Save this value to the database
    wp_update_comment( $comment );

}
```

but i am getting this error:
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/SandyBlog/wp-includes/comment.php on line 1915

I know we can do this from admin panel but i want to do it programmatically.Please suggest me what to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you try to automatically approve every comment without moderating them? If so just uncheck the following settings under Settings > Discussion

- Comment must be manually approved
- Comment author must have a previously approved comment

Comment: Thanks josh for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
// Get the comment object
$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );

// Get the comment object
$comment_id = $_comment->comment_ID;

// Set its to not approve comment
wp_set_comment_status($comment_id, '0');
```